# Spring Declarative Transactions help needed

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I am writing a quartz job which will run on a daily basis and will update a particular database table.

The logic for the same is as follows:

1) Fetch all entities [as we are using hibernate] which needs and update
2) Iterate them, get each object and call a separate private method to perform the update.

The above two steps are performed inside a public method representing the quartz job.

I want to make sure that even if update for any of the record fails, it should not affect the other records. For example, if 50 records are found and an error occurs while updating the 31st record it should not rollback the previous 30 updates.

Can someone please suggest which transaction methodology should be used here? Should it be PROPAGATION_NOT_SUPPORTED or PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW or any other?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Using declarative transaction management with private methods is difficult ... see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#tx-decl-explained for details.

For your use case I see two options:

1. use programmatic transaction management, so if somebody reads the code it is obvious where the transaction boundaries are
2. extract a data access object for your persistence logic with a public update method (updates one entity). You can use the declarative approach with this dao.

The later approach helps you to separate concerns by not having to care about transactions and database related code in your quartz job.